# How to make tableView cell "stick" while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a SegmentedControl on a Cell at the top of my tableView (the tableView consists of all static cells)...I want the top cell (and segmentedControl) to "stick" so that it is always visible as a user scrolls through the table (see screenshot below).  Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add your segment control as a child view of your table view. Then add a table view header or an empty cell with the same height as your segment control.

Comment: Its very easy, Just drag and drop segmentedControl into header view of the table.

Comment: @aBilal17 it won't be "sticked".

Comment: Proper way is to not use TableViewController but UIViewController with tableView. Then add segmented control as a regular view, so it won't be affected by scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for applying this behavior you should add it as a *header view* instead of a cell. Header views in table view does "stick". But since you are adding static cells (UITableViewController), even if you tried to add a header view to the table view it won't apply the sticking behavior.

As a *workaround* you might need to add a new UIViewController contains a view on the top (the header view) and a container view, as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it's a little messy since the tableView has views that are dependent upon values of the SegmentedControl, i.e. I'll have to do some type of a protocol/delegation to pass messages to the tableView from an external VC. I'll leave open for a little while to make sure there's no other way before I mark as accepted.  

Comment: @GarySabo sure! hope someone provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The one hackish solution which pops to my mind is:

Declare header in your VC, or hold the reference:

```
private var header: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 40))
```

Add it as a subview of tableView and set content inset equal to height of the header.

```
tableView.addSubview(header)
tableView.contentInset.top = header.frame.height
```

If your header use autolayout you will need to call
`view.layoutIfNeeded()` before setting content inset

and then for header to stick always to the top of tableView:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    header.frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```